# Splitting one row in 2 column in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

trying to split the data in 2 columns with '/' delimeter. tried uising Split function but it did not work

```
SELECT
s.siteid,
s.notes, --This is the column that CSI uses for the description.
split(s.notes,'/')  part1
FROM AloomaTestBeta.SCSERVICES s
```

and also tried this one but gave me an Error: Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)

```
SELECT
s.siteid,
s.notes, --This is the column that CSI uses for the description.
split(s.notes,'/') [OFFSET(0)] part1,
split(s.notes,'/') [OFFSET(1)] part2
FROM AloomaTestBeta.SCSERVICES s
```

here is the sample data

[image]

i am using this in Google biqquery and it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SAFE_OFFSET()`:

```
split(s.notes, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as part1,
split(s.notes, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] as part2
```

Comment: this works perfectly fine when i have '/ '  delimiter but if i don't have it everything comes in column part 1 which i don't want to as I am dividing the row by  language as french and English. Do you have any thoughts on this.

Comment: @Akki . . . I think you should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  I think this answers the question that you asked here.